# up down sampling and low-pass filters

Tags: lowpass-filter, downsampling, decimation

I am trying to figure out what seems very trivial thing about down sampling and up sampling. The problem that I am facing is how to find the effects of up sample on a signal followed by a filter and/or a filter followed by down sampling. Here is a problem related to this from the Oppenhiem and Schafer book.

[image]

I am trying to see what happens to x[n] after it pass the hlp[n], considering that hlp[n] has wc = pi/4. Will there be a gain on this or just the frequency is affected?

Please help, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this will act like low pass filter with $\pi/2$ instead of $\pi/4$ cutoff frequency

Answer (score 0):

do you go to concordia by any chance? this question looks waaaayyy to famaliar. :)

I asked a similar question a while back, the answers provided there should help.

[up sample and down sample](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/18737/up-sample-and-down-sample)